# How do I create scoped events?

Tags: c#, events, prism, cab, scsf

I am about to migrate a cab application created with smart client software factory from in 2009. Everything seemed to be straight until the event aggregator. I need to have code like this:

```
//publish in current unity conainer
customerInfoSavedEvent.Publish(payload, PubliscationScope.CurrentContainer);

//publish in all unity conainers in hierarchy 
customerInfoSavedEvent.Publish(payload, PubliscationScope.GlobalContainer);
```

Other suggestions outside this are welcome. The goal is to retain the events system in the workitem infrastructure of cab/scsf.

Comment: Prism events aren't quite the same so you don't have scoped events. One way around it is to include details about the event in the payload. The subscriber can specify a delegate to filter the event before the event handler fires.

Comment: Thanks,going to do that